# Get the row and column of a datable cell while using mouse Hover function

Tags: datatables

I am new to using datatables.

Requirement is : To get the cell- row no & col no when I hover over the table (4 column table). When i hover the mouse over the 2nd column of each row I have to show a popup describing the values of the 2nd column (which I have kept hidden in the 4th column)

I searched around and I got info on getting the column no, but not the row no and col no at the same time.

The code i used is as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bSortClasses": false
    } );

    $('td').hover( function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        var iCol = $('td').index(this)%4 ;
        console.log(iCol);
        var iRow = $('tr').index(this) ;
        console.log(iRow);

        if(iCol=='1'){ // if 2nd col
        console.log(aData[3]);// this is the description i have to show- How to show this value 
        }
    }, function() {

    } );

});
```

In the above code, I get the col no but my iRow returns -1 and aData[iCol] shows me error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ’3′ of undefined`. This is because aData itself is undefined. So what do i have to use in order to get the value in the 4th column

I tried doing the following methods as well :

1. If I change the hover for `tr` instead of `td` --> $('tr').hover( function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) .... , I get the row no but not the column on my iCol returns -1.
2. If I change the hover to check for the table #example --> $('#example').hover( function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) .... , I get -1 for both iRow and iCol

I tried using

```
var data = oTable .fnGetData(this);
console.log(data);
```

data returns me

1. the column value for  $('td').hover ...
2. row value for $('tr').hover.... But then since i dont hv the iCol value I am not able to get the data[iCol].

Comment: You'll get a lot more useful answers if your question is easier to read. Try to clean it up a little! Good luck

Comment: `Cannot read property ’3′ of undefined` and the only 3 I see is aData[`3`] and its in a undefined meaning `aData` is undefined

Comment: Hi SSpoke, i used the syntax function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) similar to the one we use for fnRowCallback. Here it is not working. Do you know what to use to get the value for column 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the row and the column

```
$('#example tbody td').hover( function( e) {
  var iPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
  var iCol = iPos [1];
  var iRow = iPos[0];
```

});

Thanks